# Regex pattern for getting the the string value from the filename

Tags: php, regex

I'm stuck on getting the value with an underscore separator.
I used preg_match(PHP) but didn't get the correct regex pattern.
This is the sample pattern of the filename.

xxxx_get-thisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
get-thisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
getThisValue_20200728173715594600.zip

All I want is to get the get-thisValue or getThisValue string on the filename pattern, thanks in advance
btw here is my code

```
<?php 
$filename = 'xxxx_get-thisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip';
preg_match('/(.*_)?(.*)_[0-9]+.zip/', $filename, $matches);
echo $prefix = $matches[2];
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use for example a capture group:

```
([^_\s]+)(?:_[^\n_-]+)?_\d+\.zip$
```

**Explanation**

- `([^_\s]+)` Capture group 1, match any char except `_` (or a whitespace)
- `(?:_[^\n_-]+)?` Optionally match `_` and then any char except `_` or `-`
- `_\d+\.zip` Match `_` 1+ digits and `.zip`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fcg3O9/1)

Example

```
$re = '/([^_\s]+)(?:_[^\n_-]+)?_\d+\.zip$/m';
$str = 'xxxx_get-thisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
get-thisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
getThisValue_20200728173715594600.zip
xxxx_get-thisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
xxxx_getthisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
1111_get-thisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
1111_getthisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
get-thisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
getthisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
get-thisValue_20200728173715594600.zip
getthisValue_20200728173715594600.zip';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => get-thisValue
    [1] => get-thisValue
    [2] => getThisValue
    [3] => get-thisValue
    [4] => getthisValue
    [5] => get-thisValue
    [6] => getthisValue
    [7] => get-thisValue
    [8] => getthisValue
    [9] => get-thisValue
    [10] => getthisValue
)
```

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/BRZdv).

Comment: sorry I've missed several patterns, btw this is the complete possible pattern of the filename.      

xxxx_get-thisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
xxxx_getthisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
1111_get-thisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
1111_getthisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
get-thisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
getthisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip 
get-thisValue_20200728173715594600.zip 
getthisValue_20200728173715594600.zip

Comment: @EazylleConcepcion Like this? https://regex101.com/r/2SgUrQ/1

Comment: sorry I've missed this part, there is a dash on the more details part. this is the example xxxx_get-thisValue_more-details_20200728173715594600.zip, 1111_get-thisValue_more-details_20200728173715594600.zip, get-thisValue_more-details_20200728173715594600.zip thanks in advance

Comment: @EazylleConcepcion How can you differentiate between the gethisvalue part and the `_more-details` part? Are there any rules or logic for the different parts?

Comment: most likely the same, the get-thisValue is a module indicated on the report and the more-details is a note and it's optional.

Comment: @EazylleConcepcion Is there a pattern or are there mandatory characters in the `getthisValue` part? As it is right now, there is a leading optional part followed by an underscore, but the `more-details` part can also contain the same characters so how can you tell where it starts and ends? Can you create a regex101 example link with real life example strings?

Comment: or maybe we change this from getting the get-thisValue to removing the 1111_ or xxxx_ and it's optional.

Comment: @EazylleConcepcion In that case you can remove that first `1111_` or `xxxx_` from the start of the string like https://regex101.com/r/EVqOem/1 or you can optionally match those specific strings https://regex101.com/r/J5r1qh/1

Comment: what I mean is a regex that removes the 1111_ or xxxx_, the sample format of this is 12345_ or sample_, btw there is no combi like 123abc and special character.

Comment: I create a new one for this kindly check the link please,  thanks in advance [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72965367/regex-pattern-that-remove-the-first-part-of-the-filename)